# Multilevel Inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, oop

Let's say I have a base class A and class B derives from it. Class C from B and so on .....
Y from Z.

Who will be responsible for initializing the data members of class A, when I instantiate class Z?

Comment: the answer depends on whether the direct inheritance from A is `virtual` or not

Comment: Could you please tell me the answer in both cases? I was just thinking about it and was curious.

Comment: well for non-`virtual` inheritance it's class B. that's the usual situation and it's simple. but all inheritance chains with `virtual` inheritance from A share the same A sub-object, and so there is potentially a bit of conflict about who initializes that part. the rule in C++ is that it's done by *the most derived class*, i.e. Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inherit from a class, the base class's constructor is called prior to the derived class's. You can control what gets passed to it using the initializer list:

```
struct A
{
    A();
    A(int);
}

struct B
{
    B(){} // A() is called implicitly.
    B(int x) : A(x) {} // A(int) is called explicitly.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any class derived along the chain can be *responsible* for initializing the data members depending on their accessibility.

One common method is to have class A`s constructor demand values for the data members.  Class B would add these variables to it's constructor and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It could be any of the classes A through Z, it completely depends on your situation.  If class A takes param a b and c in its constructor then class B must provide these, if it in turn in its constructor expects a b c to be passed then it would be down to class C to provide these and so on.  A child class may chose to provide a value which has not been passed in the constructor though and therefore subsequent children would no longer need to provide this value.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the constructor of A will be responsible for the initialisation of A's data members, as classes are constructed from the top down, or Base-before-Derived.  This is why you can't use a pure virtual member function in a constructor, as the derived class in which it is defined has not been created yet.

Answer (score 0):

Every constructor of every class constructs all the immediate non-virtual base classes. That explains recursively what happens in your setup.

By contrast, virtual base classes are constructed by the constructor of the most-derived class.

Here's a typical example which mentions the base constructors explicitly:

```
struct A { A(int, int) { /* ... */ ; };

struct B : A { B(char, bool) : A(2, 3) { /* ... */ };

struct C : B { C() : B('x', false) { /* ... */ };

C c;  // calls A::A(2, 3), then B::B('x', false), then C::C()
```